# Shift recyclerview focus to last element in the list

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am using recyclerview to display messages in a chat window. However, when a new message is being edited, the recycler view focus should be on the last element. I expect there would be some way to shift the focus of a recyclerview to last element instead of first.

Comment: use `recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);` position is your index of last item inserted.

Comment: you can add this as the answer as it solved my problem.

Comment: @VipulAsri please put your comment as answer as it solved the question. You would help other guys

Answer (score 51, accepted):

use `recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);`

***position*** is your index of last item inserted. This will move your  the `RecyclerView` focus on the last element.

Answer (score 18):

Use can add any of the two lines on your LinearLayoutManager object to scroll your recyclerview to the bottom ...

```
llm.setStackFromEnd(true);
```

OR

```
llm.setReverseLayout(true);
```

Comment: it populates the list from bottom. this was not something i was looking for. Vipul's answer solved my problem. BTW,thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Use

```
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position)
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

where position is the index of last element

```
recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount()-1
```

use this to get last element.

This worked for me .

Comment: Best and must detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways by which you can do.

1: When you are creating any LayoutManager for the RecyclerView, Make the last parameter in its constructor as `true`.

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,true);
```

2: Simply tell the RecyclerView to scroll to the last position.

```
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(lastPosition);
```

Answer (score 2):

use `layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);` instead of this.

**Sample**

```
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.list);
    layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make Sure This position is the position of the item which  you want to view.

```
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use below code. Here **recyclerView.getBottom()** defines the position to be focus

```
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView.getBottom());
```

Answer (score 0):

use the below code in **Kotlin**

```
binding.recyclerViewMessage.smoothScrollToPosition(if (list.size > 1) list.size - 1 else list.size);
```

this is working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);

Answer (score -1):

You can use **app:stackFromEnd="true"** in your recycler view XML code like:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
  android:id="@+id/message_list"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_above="@id/message_input"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  app:stackFromEnd="true" />
```

Comment: use `layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);` instead of this.